# How to use Angular @Injectable with a function (not a class)

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm creating a service for an Angular (2+) application and all the documentation uses classes, but I prefer to write the service as a function.

Here's what I want to work (but doesn't):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

export const AframeMessengerService = Injectable()(function AframeMessengerService() {
    console.log('aframe messenger');
});
```

With this, I get this error in the file which injects it:

```
Cannot find name 'AframeMessengerService'.
```

Here's what does work, but is not what I want:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class AframeMessengerService {
    constructor() {
        console.log('aframe messenger');
    }
}
```

Comment: what are trying to do? a class is a function

Comment: @Maximus I'm trying to use the first syntax and not the second. I'm aware that a class is a function. I don't want to use the class syntax.

Comment: do you intent to Inject anything into `AframeMessengerService`?

Comment: @Maximus Yes. I intend to inject another service which I plan to write in this same fashion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically you're doing everything correct here:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

export const AframeMessengerService = Injectable()(function AframeMessengerService() {
    console.log('aframe messenger');
});
```

Now you need to add this to module providers:

```
import { AframeMessengerService } from './a.service';

@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [AframeMessengerService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And inject it like this:

```
import { AframeMessengerService } from './a.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  ...
})
export class AppComponent {   
  constructor(@Inject(AframeMessengerService) s) { }
```

One thing to note is that when you will be injecting services into `AframeMessengerService` you need to pass an index of parameter:

```
import { Inject, Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';

const AframeMessengerService = Injectable()(function AframeMessengerService(i) {
  console.log('aframe messenger');
});

Inject(Injector)(AframeMessengerService, null, 0);
                                         ^^^^^^^

export { AframeMessengerService };
```

Comment: It works! Thank you. Angular language service (VSCode extension) is having trouble with it though. It says "Can't resolve all parameters for MyComponent in /some/path"...

Comment: @KevinBeal, sorry, can't help there. Don't use VSCode. In WebStorm everything is OK. Just curios, why do you need that?

Comment: I guess I don't need it. I thought I would mention it in the off-chance you were aware of any clues that would help me. It has been acting strangely in other ways though... At any rate, thanks for your help! :)

Comment: @KevinBeal, you're welcome. I'm assuming it's for educational purposes then) Having such code in production would probably be confusing

Comment: How would one modify this so that the functions parameters could be fulfilled by Angular's DI?